# How to convert PNG to PDF

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I've see everywhere that a "convert" command works. But I'm using windows and convert does the following

> "In computing, convert is a command-line utility included in the Windows NT operating system line. It is used to convert volumes using the FAT file systems to NTFS."

How can I manage to do this in Windows? I have PDFTK installed.

Comment: `convert` as described above is from the ImageMagick utilities, which are on Linux/other *nixes and ported to Windows.  See http://www.thekoikeepers.com/ImageMagick-5.5.7/www/windows.html

Comment: Windows 10 has "Microsoft Print to PDF" have you tried printing to that? open your PNG (or image) in whatever editor you use and then use that printer.

Comment: MY answer IS not a comment!  I posted a valid answer and thus it should not be treated as a 'comment'

Comment: @Aaron.S "have you tried printing to that?" is a suggestion not an answer.

Comment: If they were JPEG's I'd suggest https://github.com/josch/img2pdf

Answer (score 10):

You are almost certainly seeing references to [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), which has a `convert` utility that potentially allows `.png` to `.pdf` conversion e.g.:

```
convert image1.png image2.png image3.png output.pdf
```

You will need to [install ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) to use its `convert` utility (make sure it's properly added to your Windows PATH).

I am not personally familiar with PDFTK (so I could be wrong) but I get the impression it is primarily used in conjunction with ImageMagick because it does splitting and merging (not conversion).

---

*Alternatively, with more recent versions of ImageMagick (v7+), you can potentially use either:*

```
magick convert image1.png image2.png image3.png output.pdf
```

*or simply:*

```
magick image1.png image2.png image3.png output.pdf
```

*as well.*

Comment: Unfortunately ImageMagick's PDF support has been _unusably_ buggy in some recent versions – consuming gigabytes of memory even for trivial conversions.

Comment: i used now [img2pdf](https://github.com/josch/img2pdf) for jpg to pdf converting. my prob the PDF is height as the image and has no OCR

Answer (score 0):

1. Windows 10 has a Print to PDF feature built into explorer.
2. Use GIMP 2.10+ and export as PDF.